# How to use regex to match on consecutive uppercase letters of unknown length

Tags: python, regex, string

Ultimately I am trying to retrieve substrings from file paths which match a particular pattern of characters and numbers. But at this point I'm just trying to get my pattern matching correct. The issue is that I don't always know how many characters are in parts of the matching strings.

For example, the broad pattern is: All uppercase followed by underscore, 4 digit number, underscore, and then mix of upper/lowercase characters and numbers.

filepath/here/of/unknown/length/**THISISTHEPATTERN_1111_Iwanttomatch**/......

so far, I have tried variations on `re.compile(r'\b[A-Z]+_\d{4}_[a-zA-Z][0-9]*')`
however this still captures cases where the UPPERCASE part of the pattern is interspersed with lowercase characters.

Here is a test case:

```
import re

file_path = [
"C:/Users/csadf/asfsf/Test",
"BEAVERHEAD_2020_thisisatestQL1",
"BEAVERHEAD_2020_thisisatest",
"BEAVeRHEAD_2020_thisisatest",
"C:/Users/csadf/asfsf/Test/BEAVERHEAD_2020_thisisaTest1",
"C:/Users/csadf/asfsf/Test/BEAVERHEAD_202_thisisaTest1",
"C:/Users/csadf/asfsf/Test/BEAVERHEAD_2020_thisisaTest1/data/dfjt/rth"]

projectname_pattern = re.compile(r'\b[A-Z]+[a-z]{0}[A-Z]+_\d{4}_[a-zA-Z][0-9]*')


for i in file_path:
    if projectname_pattern.search(i):
        print("Found a match: ",i) 
    else:   
        print("no match")
```

In this example I want it to return:

```
no match
Found a match
Found a match
no match
Found a match
no match
Found a match
```

edit: corrected a typo in the test cases. Also, appears I unwittingly answered my own question. The above regex appears to work.

Comment: try, ``r'\b[A-Z]+_\d{4}_[A-Za-z0-9]+'`` ?

Comment: I'm having trouble differenciating between test cases 4 and 5...both contain at least one uppercase letter, followed by at least one lowercase letter, then the rest of the format. "BEAVeRHEAD" and "TestBEAVERHEAD" both contain lowercase letters interrupting the format.

Comment: @jdabtieu, I had a typo in there, as written, you are correct there was no difference. I have corrected the test case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test output shows that your regex is working perfectly to your stated pattern:

```
no match:  C:/Users/csadf/asfsf/Test
Found a match:  BEAVERHEAD_2020_thisisatestQL1
Found a match:  BEAVERHEAD_2020_thisisatest
no match:  BEAVeRHEAD_2020_thisisatest
no match:  C:/Users/csadf/asfsf/TestBEAVERHEAD_2020_thisisaTest1
no match:  C:/Users/csadf/asfsf/Test/BEAVERHEAD_202_thisisaTest1
Found a match:  C:/Users/csadf/asfsf/Test/BEAVERHEAD_2020_thisisaTest1/data/dfjt/rth
```

The case of C:/Users/csadf/asfsf/TestBEAVERHEAD_2020_thisisaTest1 is not matched because there is no word boundary (\b) before the BEAVERHEAD.

Can you double-check your requirements and restate?

Comment: Thank you @KateYoak, it does appear to work. Not sure why I didn't think it was. But  Thank you for the confirmation